# Did I commit sin ? I am confused. My past is hitting me

Tags: hadith, sin, punishment, tawba, cheating

Did I commit sin ? I had a boyfriend I broke up with him in 2019. We had some valid reason to break up. But after I broke I thought he cheated but I never caught him red handed. But many thing was indicating. And when my friend asked me why I broke up I told them he cheated. But most of my friends didn’t know my ex-boyfriend.  I wasn’t sure if he actually cheated. Now I don’t have any contact with him. We don’t even talk with each other for years. Suddenly my past actions are hitting me. Now what should I do ?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking about. Having relationships other than marriage (such as boy friends) is haram.

Comment: I’m saying I broke up with him long ago. But I suspected after breakup that he may be cheated on me. So I said to my friend  they asked that he cheated. But I never caught him red handed.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop answering with that and instead just say we had many problems so we broke up or find any normal reason if you have to face the question again.
you commited a sin but allah is merciful and the moment you try to change and stop doing whatever sin you do and ask for forgiveness allah will forgive you no matter what you did , even he change your bad deeds to good one.

- in general ask for forgiveness and seek to not commit the sin again.